# How to pass loaded struct array to other function in multiple file (c++)

Tags: c++

On my mainfile, I wish to pass my loaded struct array from first function to second function ,both functions are in the source file(in.cpp).  I was not able to do so even if I defined struct on main file, because firstly array cannot be return only pass by reference; I tried pass by reference also but does not work

```
    #include "internetUsage.h"
    #include "abc.h"
    #include<fstream>
    #include<cstring>
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;



    int main()
    {

    char filename[20];
     ifstream infile;
     cout<<"enter file name: \n";
     cin.getline(filename,20);
     infile.open(filename);


       newRecord(infile,filename);
       updateRecord(infile,filename);


    return 0;
    }
```

This is my source file (in.cpp); after I loaded my struct array in my first function, I could not figure out how to display on my second function(updateRecord())

```
    #include "internetUsage.h"
    #include "abc.h"
    #include <fstream>
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;


    void newRecord(ifstream &infile,char filename[])
    {

      Info customer[50];

                for(int i; i<6; i++)
                {

                  infile>>customer[i].num;                
                  infile>>customer[i].name;
                  infile>>customer[i].name2;
                  infile>>customer[i].charge;

                }
  }



   void updateRecord(ifstream &infile,char filename[])
  {


              for(int j; j<6; j++)
             {
              cout<<customer[j].num<<endl;
              cout<<customer[j].name<<endl; 
              cout<<customer[j].name2<<endl; 
              cout<<customer[j].charge<<endl;                  
             }       
    }
```

This is my header file for two functions(internetUsage.h)

```
#include <fstream>
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void newRecord(ifstream &infile, char filename[]);
void updateRecord(ifstream &infile,char filename[]);
```

This is my header file for struct(abc.h)

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;


struct Info
{   
int num;   
char name[200];
char name2[200];
double charge;
};
```

Comment: What is the `loaded struct array` ? is that the local copy of `Info[]`? I really have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: Looks very much like homework... otherwise needs a thorough redesign to resemble some ghost of object orientation...

Comment: I'm so sorry, I just had programming experience for 4 months; I still still need to time to learn.

Comment: Yes, it is a homework, I'm a beginner computer science student; that should be local copy of Info[].

Answer (score 0):

you should define it  `Info customer[50];` as global variable , not local variable

Answer (score 0):

1. define Info customer[50]; in main(),
2. Change newRecord() interface to add two parameters: Info * customer, int sizeCustomer
3. Change newRecord() internal loop to control customer's overflow, something like "if(j >= sizeCustomer) break;"
4. Change newRecord() interface to return number of customers have been read
5. Change updateRecord() interface to add two parameters: const Info * customer, int actualCustomerSize
6. Change updateRecord() internal loop to run for actualCustomerSize only, for example by modifing for(;j!=actualCustomerSize;)
7. Make changes in main()
8. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Declare that structure as global in the file where you are loading that structure and then use the extern keyword along with the structure name in all the files where you want to use that function.

DO check this link:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/